# Comparison of memcache, redis and ehcache as distributed caching framework

Tags: caching, memcached, ehcache, redis, distributed-caching

One of the decisions I need to make is what caching framework to use in my system. With so many to choose from, I am currently investigating redis, ehcache and memcached.

Can anyone point to performance benchmarks of these three particular frameworks? Also an overview of their features - I am particularly interested in disadvantages, ie. situations where you would use one over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small feature comparison is here: http://toddrobinson.com/appfabric/appfabric-cache-feature-comparisons/

**UPDATE** 25.02.2016

Dead link fixed thanks to WebArchive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20140205010302/http://toddrobinson.com/appfabric/appfabric-cache-feature-comparisons/

Comment: FYI - This hyperlink is now broken.

Comment: its always better to provide the answer instead of "just" pointing to URL, since URL may go invalid.

Comment: Down voted since link is broken and no efforts to post answer . even copy post would have helped here .

Comment: Voted Down since the link is broken

Comment: Voted down since link is broken and archive.org link doesn't talk about ehcache